# xQuery substring problem

Tags: xquery

I now have a full path for a file as a string like:

```
   "/db/Liebherr/Content_Repository/Techpubs/Topics/HyraulicPowerDistribution/Released/TRN_282C_HYD_MOD_1_Drive_Shaft_Rev000.xml"
```

However, now I need to take out only the folder path, so it will be the above string without the last back slash content like:

```
"/db/Liebherr/Content_Repository/Techpubs/Topics/HyraulicPowerDistribution/Released/"
```

But it seems that the substring() function in xQuery only has substring(string,start,len) or substring(string,start), I am trying to figure out a way to specify the last occurence of the backslash, but no luck.

Could experts help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This can be done even with a single XPath 2.0 (subset of XQuery) expression**:

```
substring($fullPath, 
          1, 
          string-length($fullPath) - string-length(tokenize($fullPath, '/')[last()])
          )
```

**where `$fullPath` should be substituted with the actual string, such as**:

```
"/db/Liebherr/Content_Repository/Techpubs/Topics/HyraulicPowerDistribution/Released/TRN_282C_HYD_MOD_1_Drive_Shaft_Rev000.xml"
```

Comment: OK, but why would you prefer this one over the variant using a single call to fn:replace?

Comment: @Gunther: Somehow yes. I always prefer analytical solutions to generative ones. My solution just takes apart -- it doesn't modify or construct something that doesn't already exist. Anyway, a RegEx can quickly become unreadable and is a potential disaster.

Answer (score 2):

Try out the tokenize() function (for splitting a string into its component parts) and then re-assembling it, using everything but the last part.

```
let $full-path := "/db/Liebherr/Content_Repository/Techpubs/Topics/HyraulicPowerDistribution/Released/TRN_282C_HYD_MOD_1_Drive_Shaft_Rev000.xml",
    $segments := tokenize($full-path,"/")[position() ne last()]
return
  concat(string-join($segments,'/'),'/')
```

For more details on these functions, check out their reference pages:

- [fn:tokenize()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize)
- [fn:string-join()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-join)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: Yes, but why would I want to? :)

Comment: @_Evan: I am asking myself a similar question: Why on Earth, would I want to modify or construct something that already exists?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Better code readability at negligible expense.

Answer (score 2):

[fn:replace](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-replace) can do the job with a regular expression:

```
replace("/db/Liebherr/Content_Repository/Techpubs/Topics/HyraulicPowerDistribution/Released/TRN_282C_HYD_MOD_1_Drive_Shaft_Rev000.xml", 
        "[^/]+$", 
        "")
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code tokenizes, removes the last token, replaces it with an empty string, and joins back.

```
string-join(
  (
    tokenize(
        "/db/Liebherr/Content_Repository/Techpubs/Topics/HyraulicPowerDistribution/Released/TRN_282C_HYD_MOD_1_Drive_Shaft_Rev000.xml",
        "/"
      )[position() ne last()],
    ""
  ),
  "/"
)
```

It seems to return the desired result on try.zorba-xquery.com. Does this help?